# Need hints on how to solve this

Tags: python, integer, wolfram-mathematica

`a, b, c, d, e, f, g & h` are different integers.

If `a*b + c*d = e*f + g*h = n`

What is the minimum value of `n`?

Obviously a for loop will take forever if we consider the 8 numbers with 8 loops. Is there a simpler way to solve this?

I need some hints to solve it in Mathematical or Python.

Comment: You say `a, b, c, d, e, f, g & h are different integers`. Are they defined ? There is too many unknown in your problem. Plus SO is for helping on *code* not maths equation ... provide a code or post on math exchange.

Comment: The answer approaches negative infinity as per common sense. The `a*b` block would factor to some negative number and the `c*d` block would factor to another negative number which when added together, you have 4 variables `e*f+g*h` which can be anything as long as they're not the same numbers as a,b,c, and d to make the statement on the left true. Are you sure you don't mean `positive integers`?

Comment: all are positive integers. Sorry I didn't mention that..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to get the all combinations of the numbers from set {1..9}.then use a generator expression within `min` function for find the expected result.

```
>>> S=range(10)
>>> 
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> min(a*b+c*d for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h in combinations(S,8) if a*b + c*d == e*f + g*h)
```

But since this won't gives any result, instead of `range(10)` you can use larger `range()`.

Comment: The question is unclear, this solution brings a hint on how it can be solved.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yep, just fixed!

Comment: Also use `combinations_with_replacement()` from `itertools` as you want to iter on repeated elements. And you will have results ;)

Comment: @Cyrbil No it shouldn't contains duplicated elements. ;)

Comment: this will not work, you need to test all the permutations of each combination.

Comment: indeed, if you import `permutations` and make that `permutations(range(1,9))` you get the result `31`

Answer (score 1):

For positive integers, (1 to 8)

```
First@Sort@DeleteCases[({a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} = #;
      If[(n = a*b + c*d) == e*f + g*h,
       {n, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}]) & /@ Permutations[Range[8]], Null]
```

> {31, 1, 7, 4, 6, 2, 8, 3, 5}

Minimum n = 31

Comment: That was fast. Thanks Chris Degnen